# Laravel 5.5 Composer update But Pop a Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to deploy a Laravel project onto an AWS Ubuntu server. I cloned my project to the Apache server at `/var/www/html/laravel/myproject/` and ran

```
sudo composer update
```

After which I received the following error:

> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating optimized autoload files
>   Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover
>   Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
>   Discovered Package: intervention/image
>   Discovered Package: laravel/passport
>   Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
>   Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
>   Package manifest generated successfully.

How can I prevent this error from accuring again?

Comment: ```composer update``` not work?

Comment: yes,its not work

Comment: try `composer self-update`

Comment: plz delete composer.lock in root laravel, and composer install and update.

Comment: You should always use `composer install` to deploy. That will make sure you have exactly same "package versions" in development and production based on `composer.lock` file.

Comment: i used sudo composer self-update command and result is You are already using composer version 1.7.2 (stable channel).

Comment: The user you run composer from, needs to be able to write to the `/var/www/html/laravel/myproject/`. Fix the permissions on the folder, so you don't need to run composer as sudo.

Also, never do `composer update` on your production/staging server. It will only generate git conflicts on the `composer.lock` file. Do `composer install`.